# Accessing global variable from within method Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2

Hey guys I'm wondering how to access variables from the global scope (this) from within 2 methods. Help appreciated

```
location: any;

    doSomethingOne() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                this.location = resp;
                this.doSomething();

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error getting location', error);
            });
    }

    doSomething() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxx/api/' + this.location.coords.latitude + '/' + this.location.coords.longitude + '/5')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                resolve(this.data);
            });
    });
    }
```

How can I access this.location from within a Promise? Console shows 'undefined' when accessing it

Comment: `this` isn't global scope. `window` is. If you're trying to get *object* scope, arrow function as `then` callback should do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
doSomethingOne(): Observalbe<any> {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                 return new Promise(resolve => {
        return this.http.get('http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxx/api/' + resp.coords.latitude + '/' + resp.coords.longitude + '/5')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                return resolve(this.data);
            });
        });

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error getting location', error);
            });
    }
```